# Proof that $P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$ $-P(A \cap B)$ $-P(B \cap C)$ $-P(A \cap C)$ $+P(A \cap B \cap C)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Interesting Probability question. I have too proof that

\begin{align*}
 P(A \cup B \cup C)
 &= P(A) + P(B) + P(C) \\
 &\quad - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) \\
 &\quad + P(A \cap B \cap C).
\end{align*}

Using probability introductory formulas and theorems. I understand fully when using the Venn diagram but I'm having trouble proving it mathematically.

I have tried the following but haven't been able to continue.

\begin{align*}
 P(A \cup B \cup C)
 &= P(A \cup (B \cup C) \tag{1} \\
 &= P(A)+ P((B \cup C) \cap A')\tag{2} \\
 &= P(A)+ P((B \cap A') \cup (C \cap A'))\tag{3} \\
 &= P(A)+ P(B \cap A')+ P(C \cap A')\tag{4}
\end{align*}

We also know that

\begin{align*}
 \begin{split}
  P(B)&=P(A \cap B)+P(B \cap A'), \\
  P(C)&=P(A \cap C)+P(C \cap A').
 \end{split} \tag{5}
\end{align*}

Thus

\begin{align*}
 P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A)+ P(B)- P(A \cap B)+ P(C)-P(C \cap B) \tag{6}
\end{align*}

So I'm almost there but to complete the equation I'm still missing $-P(A \cap C)$ and $P(A \cap B \cap C)$.

I was thinking that $P(A \cup B \cup C)= 1- P(A' \cup B' \cup C')$ but I'm not sure how this is helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I was also successful in proving $P(A \cup B)= P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)$, and I'm trying to use the same techniques to proof this statement.

Comment: [MathJax formatting tips](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclusion Inclusion Principle Induction Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486023/exclusion-inclusion-principle-induction-proof)

Comment: I edited the question so that it reads a bit better. Thank you for the former editor **N. F. Taussig** for most of typesetting chores, and hope this is to your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the third step to the fourth step, you did not include any intersection term.

\begin{align}
&P(A) + P( B \cap A') \cup (C \cap A') \\&=P(A)+ P(B \cap A') + P(C \cap A') \color{blue}{- P(B \cap C \cap A')}\\
&=P(A)+P(B)-P(B \cap A) + P(C)-P(C \cap A) -(P(B\cap C)-P(A \cap B \cap C))
\end{align}

Comment: Just to clarify... how are you going from the blue segment to −(P(B∩C)−P(A∩B∩C))?? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: $P((B \cap C) \cap A') + P((B \cap C) \cap A) = P(B \cap C)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be P((B∩C)∩A′) - P((B∩C)∩A)=P(B∩C)??

Comment: If you let $D = B \cap C$, we get $P(D \cap A') +P(D \cap A) = P(D)$. That should be a plus.

Comment: ohhh is see... how to you manage to get (positive) P(AnBnC) as seen in the statement though? because you need to add that intersection after subtracting all the others.

Comment: NEVER MIND... my bad

Answer (score 0):

Use the "change of variables" $B\cup C=D$ and everything follows.