# Exclusion-inclusion principle proof

Tags: induction, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to proof the inclusion-exclusion principle and I can't find anything on the internet that matches the formula that I have to proof. I need to proof the following.

$$\#(\bigcup_{j=1}^{n} X_{j}) = \sum_{D \subset E_{n}} (-1)^{\#D-1}\#X_{D}$$ where $$X_{D}=\bigcap_{j\in D} X_{j}$$ So for example $X_{\{i,j,k\}} = X_{i} \cap X_{j} \cap X_{k}$

I am trying to proof this by induction.

Basic step: $n=1$  then $$\#(X_{1}) =\#(X_{1})$$ which is trivial.

Now assume that the formula is correct for $n=k$, namely $$\#(\bigcup_{j=1}^{k} X_{j}) = \sum_{D \subset E_{k}} (-1)^{\#D-1}\#X_{D}.$$ We will proof that it is also correct for $n=k+1$. So $$\#(\bigcup_{j=1}^{k+1} X_{j}) = \sum_{D \subset E_{k+1}} (-1)^{\#D-1}\#X_{D}.$$ I have no idea what my next step should be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclusion Inclusion Principle Induction Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486023/exclusion-inclusion-principle-induction-proof)

Comment: I had a look at it, but I can not understand my situation with help from that proof. Thanks for the try.

Comment: $$\#(\bigcup_{j=1}^{k+1} X_{j}) = \#((\bigcup_{j=1}^{k} X_{j})\cup  X_{k+1})$$